# javascript : Create visible indentation by id - parentId relationship in flatList

Tags: javascript, list, recursion, tree, indentation

I have a flatlist with hierarchy structure
represented by ID parentID relationship like so:

```
[
      { id: "100", bezeichnung: "Node 1", parentId: null },
      { id: "101", bezeichnung: "Node 1 A", parentId: "100" },
      { id: "102", bezeichnung: "Node 1 B", parentId: "100" },
      { id: "200", bezeichnung: "Node 2", parentId: null },
      { id: "201", bezeichnung: "Node 2 A", parentId: "200" },
      { id: "202", bezeichnung: "Node 2 B", parentId: "200" },
      { id: "204", bezeichnung: "Node 2 BA", parentId: "202" },
      { id: "203", bezeichnung: "Node 3 A", parentId: "200" }
    ]
```

I like to translate this into something like this:

```
[
      { id: "100", bezeichnung: "Node 1", parentId: null, indent: 0 },
      { id: "101", bezeichnung: "Node 1 A", parentId: "100", indent: 1 },
      { id: "102", bezeichnung: "Node 1 B", parentId: "100", indent: 1 },
      { id: "200", bezeichnung: "Node 2", parentId: null, indent: 0 },
      { id: "201", bezeichnung: "Node 2 A", parentId: "200", indent: 1 },
      { id: "202", bezeichnung: "Node 2 B", parentId: "200", indent: 1 },
      { id: "204", bezeichnung: "Node 2 BA", parentId: "202", indent: 2 },
      { id: "203", bezeichnung: "Node 3 A", parentId: "200", indent: 1 }
    ]
```

note that the above shown Ids might be arbitrary uuids and not 0,100,200 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have is a list of nodes of a tree. Tree traversal is often most intuitively done using recursion:

```js
let input = [
    { id: "100", bezeichnung: "Node 1", parentId: null },
    { id: "101", bezeichnung: "Node 1 A", parentId: "100" },
    { id: "102", bezeichnung: "Node 1 B", parentId: "100" },
    { id: "200", bezeichnung: "Node 2", parentId: null },
    { id: "201", bezeichnung: "Node 2 A", parentId: "200" },
    { id: "202", bezeichnung: "Node 2 B", parentId: "200" },
    { id: "204", bezeichnung: "Node 2 BA", parentId: "202" },
    { id: "203", bezeichnung: "Node 3 A", parentId: "200" }
];

input.forEach(element => element.indent = recursive(element,0))

function recursive (element, i) {
    if (!element.parentId) return i;
    return recursive(input.find(parent => parent.id === element.parentId), i+1)
}

console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-mutating version (after all, we're not barbarians, right?!), you could try something like this:

```js
const depths = (nodes, parentId = null, depth = 0) => 
  nodes .filter (n => n.parentId === parentId) 
        .flatMap (({id}) => [[id, depth], ...depths (nodes, id, depth + 1)])

const addIndents = (nodes, indents = Object .fromEntries (depths (nodes))) => 
  nodes .map (node => ({...node, indent: indents [node .id]}))

const nodes = [{id: "100", bezeichnung: "Node 1", parentId: null}, {id: "101", bezeichnung: "Node 1 A", parentId: "100"}, {id: "102", bezeichnung: "Node 1 B", parentId: "100"}, {id: "200", bezeichnung: "Node 2", parentId: null}, {id: "201", bezeichnung: "Node 2 A", parentId: "200"}, {id: "202", bezeichnung: "Node 2 B", parentId: "200"}, {id: "204", bezeichnung: "Node 2 BA", parentId: "202"}, {id: "203", bezeichnung: "Node 3 A", parentId: "200"}]

console .log ('new list: ', addIndents (nodes))
console .log ('unmodified original: ', nodes)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we first calculate `depths`, which looks something like this:

```js
[["100", 0], ["101", 1], ["102", 1], ["200", 0], ["201", 1], ["202", 1], ["204", 2], ["203", 1]]
```

then use `fromEntries` to convert that into an Object like this:

```js
{"100": 0, "101": 1, "102": 1, "200": 0, "201": 1, "202": 1, "203": 1, "204": 2}
```

Then we `map` over the input, creating new nodes by shallow-cloning the old ones and adding an `indent` property.

---

I would suggest that if you're storing that property in something like raw data, that it might better be called `depth` rather than `indent`.  Even if you're currently only planning on using it for indentation, `depth` is more generic and might apply to many more situations.